# php file automatically downloads instead of displaying in browser?

Tags: php, html

In my html file I try to link to a php file (form action):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Google</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div style="text-align: center">
        <h1>Google</h1>
          <form action="server.php" method="get">
          <input name="q" style="width: 300px" type="text">
            <br>
          <input type="submit" value="Google Search">
          <input type="submit" value="I'm Feeling Lucky">
          </form>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

`server.php` is just a little bit of html code.

When I click on the link "google search" chrome downloads the file instead of getting `server.php`

I chmod google.html to rw - r - r

I chmod server.php to rw -------- or 600

How do I get it to stop downloading `server.php` ?

Comment: nothing more than html with a .php extension

Comment: Is the file with the form an .php doc?

Comment: the name of the file is server.php and the contents inside is only html: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Google</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Coming Soon</h1>
  </body>
</html>

Comment: But is the file with the form an .php doc?

Comment: no, not a php doc, only an extension

Comment: write `<?php phpinfo() ?>` in this file, and check if your php installation is working.

Comment: I added this line of code to server.php however, even when I try to open this file with chrome, it redirects to a download

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44500/discussion-between-veelen-and-dannylee)

Answer (score 1):

You need to be running PHP on your server. If you don't have a web server, it will just download the file as there is nothing to parse the script.

Have a look at WAMP (for windows), LAMP (for linux) or MAMP (for mac)

Comment: Maybe xampp/easyphp too?

Comment: I have LAMP, PHP Version 5.5.3 installed on VM running linux