# Internet Explorer 11 downloads PHP output instead of displaying it

Tags: php, file, internet-explorer, echo

I am linking from one PHP file to another PHP file like this:

1. Build HTML in a PHP string;
2. PHP `echo` it, so the whole string displays in page;
3. That string has an anchor `<a>` tag whose `href` attribute points to another php file.

For example:

```
<? 
    $html = "<a href='http://example.com/some_path/file.php?variable=$variable'
                target='_blank'>
                <img src='image.jpg' width='18' height='18' />
             </a>";

    echo $html;
?>
```

The target PHP file also builds an HTML string that is displayed using echo.

The HTML is displayed as I need in Firefox and Chrome.  But IE (I am using v11), instead of rendering the output, downloads a PHP file whose contents are the HTML that I output using echo.

What is the problem with IE?

Comment: I just see a big lack of knowledge. You can not mix PHP and HTML. And you need a webserver like apache running.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php file automatically downloads instead of displaying in browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20900331/php-file-automatically-downloads-instead-of-displaying-in-browser)

Comment: You should install [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) and put your php files in the document root there. Just go through a basic tutorial and you will find your way. WAMP is ( Windows Apache MySQL PHP ) and it will help you run php files as a normal server.

Comment: I don't see how the above comments explain how it is working ojn Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: @Jurik Your comment about not being able to mix PHP and HTML could be considered misleading. He also states that it works fine on Chrome and Firefox suggesting he already has a working server. Please have a look at [this site](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?428795-IE-trying-to-download-all-PHP-files), it explains some possible solutions.

Comment: @Boreded yeah - I see - so the code is kinda misleading. He should at least show full line of code.

Comment: This is almost certainly due to your webserver responding with an incorrect `Content-Type` header when handling PHP files.

Comment: I have working system, in which everything works fine, execpt with IE. There can't be any problems with apache, because Firefox and Chrome understand code well (string, with HTML code prints and creates page that I want). There must be some small things, parameters or something, that IE needs to understand mine code well - or maybe there is another way to do this? If there any information that you need, just write, I will give you.